# Yii, update list by ajax, cant understand how it works;

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I have to edit a function in js that filters content of list, the code is as follows:

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
$.fn.yiiListView.update('contests-list', {
    data: {category: 2}
});
```

I could not find any documentation of `$.fn.yiiListView.update` and also data is took by url: 
/?ajax=contests-list&category=2

If I enter this link an index.php is displayed, while firebug shows html of list elements.

My goal is to make filter that would display contents of few categories, not only 2 as in example

Answer (score 1):

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/37961-fnyiilistviewupdate/

on "success" u make changes

eg.

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
$.fn.yiiListView.update('contests-list', {
    data: {category: 2},
    success: function(){ alert('i do stuff'); }
});
```